# How can I write an array formula that extracts unique values from a list only if they have a certain value in the column next to them?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, unique

I have an understanding of how index/match can be used to create a unique list of items.  I'm trying to create a unique list of items in a specific category and that is presenting a challenge to me.

For instance, say I have:

```
INDEX SPY
INDEX SPX
GOLD GLD
GOLD JNUG
GOLD GLD
INDEX SPY
```

and I want to extract only the unique GOLD values from the list.  The output should be: GLD, JNUG.

I wrote a separate array formula to check if the left column is GOLD then output the symbol from the right column but the problem I'm having is that whatever I set for false ends up looking like it's part of the list to the index/match formula.

I was thinking that maybe there's a way to remove all zero-value array elements before exposing it to index/match but I'm out of my league here.  Any suggestions on how to get the job done efficiently would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What version do you have.  This is simple with UNIQUE and FILTER.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data is in `A1:B6`. With `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` this is pretty easy now (Excel 2021+). Use the following in one cell, and it will spill:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6="GOLD"))
```

In earlier versions, it's a bit more work. You can use the following array formula (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter). Here entered into cell `D3`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(0,IF("GOLD"=$A$1:$A$6,COUNTIF($D$2:D2,$B$1:$B$6),""),0)),"")
```

You drag this formula down until you reach empty cells (the `IFERROR()` wrapper converts the `#N/A`s that appear after all unique values have been found into `""`). The "magic" is here done by `IF("GOLD"=$A$1:$A$6,COUNTIF($D$2:D2,$B$1:$B$6)`, supplying `INDEX()` with new rows only for those rows that contain "GOLD" in $A$1:$A$6.

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly and I was able to write it out and understand exactly what is happening.  The false portion off the IF function was confusing me at first because I wasn't seeing that MATCH() was ignoring it since it wasn't a zero.